# Mulesoft URL retrieve

Tags: mule, mule-component

array as an expression in the properties file, :

Myday.contextpath.getUrls [ "http://url1" , "http://url2" , "http://url3" ]

how to use ${Myday.contextpath.getUrls} in a for each scope's collection expression?

Comment: do you want to iterate over this property in for-each scope?

Comment: @sachin yes, there are 3 URL's(REST call) , I need to iterate one after other

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do the following

1. In your properties file Separate urls with comma or any delimiter

   ***Myday.contextpath.getUrls=http://url1,http://url2,http://url3***
2. then before the foreach component create a payload by splitting the entire property value

   - via dataweave example  ***p('Myday.contextpath.getUrls') splitBy ","***
   - or via MEL example ***#['${Myday.contextpath.getUrls}'.split(',')]***
3. then use the payload from step 2 as input payload to your foreach compoment, you may leave the collection field empty

Answer (score 1):

Using Mule 4.0, you can use the below syntax to iterate over values stored in property file using `for-each` scope

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection='#[p("Myday.contextpath.getUrls") splitBy ","]'>
    <logger doc:name="Logger" level="INFO" message="payload is : #[payload]" />
</foreach>
```

**Note:** Assuming that you're storing the properties without array brackets "[" "]" like this:

```
Myday.contextpath.getUrls = "http://url1,http://url2,http://url3"
```